# Accessing Headers for Net::HTTP::Post in ruby

Tags: ruby, http, header, net-library

I have the following bit of code:

```
    uri = URI.parse("https://rs.xxx-travel.com/wbsapi/RequestListenerServlet")
    https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
    https.use_ssl = true
    req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
    req.body = searchxml
    req["Accept-Encoding"] ='gzip'
    res = https.request(req)
```

This normally works  fine but the server at the other side is complaining about something in my XML and the techies there need the xml message AND the headers that are being sent.

I've got the xml message, but I can't work out how to get at the Headers  that are  being sent with the above.

Answer (score 14):

To access headers use the `each_header` method:

```
# Header being sent (the request object):
req.each_header do |header_name, header_value|
  puts "#{header_name} : #{header_value}"
end

# Works with the response object as well:
res.each_header do |header_name, header_value|
  puts "#{header_name} : #{header_value}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks that worked ... sort of.  It did not give me ALL the headers e.g. Content-Type, Content-Length and Host.  However it gave me 2 viz Accept:*/* and Accept-Encoding:gzip.  Is there some other command which will give me the others as well?

Comment: this way you see only the header you add explicitly, if you want the full headers as they are on the network, i suggest the debug output method.

Answer (score 13):

you can add:

```
https.set_debug_output $stderr
```

before the request and you will see in console the real http request sent to the server.
very useful to debug this kind of scenarios.

Comment: @ALoR Thanks for the suggestion.  Is there anyway I can send the debug output to a file as I can't run this inside a console due to the amount of parameters the routine requires.

Comment: OK I found out how to send $stderr to a  file. [code]$stderr = File.open('errlog.txt','w') [/code].  But that is giving an error in the log file of  'IOError (not opened for writing): from http.rb:1122.  Any ideas?

Comment: open a file and use the opened file variable instead of $stderr, it should write to that file instead of standard error.

Comment: @ALoR So should my code be? [code]e=File.open('errorlog.txt','w+') <newline> https.set_debug_output e [/code]?

Comment: @ALoR I tried the above and it didn't give any errors but nothing was output to the errorlog.txt file either.  However the http call was made because  I got a response back from the other server.  Should I be setting any other flag apart from https.set_debug_output e ?

Comment: Try sending the output to stdout and redirect it to a file via the command line shell. "ruby yourscript.rb > output"

Comment: I circumvented the problem by editing the routine so that I could run it in a console and that's how I got the 'Headers' that I wanted.  Thanks for all your help and suggestions.

Comment: LOVE! Very helpful for debugging!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the docs for [Net::HTTP's](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/net/1.9.2/Net/HTTP) [`post`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/net/1.9.2/Net/HTTP#post-instance_method) method. It takes the `path` of the uri value, the data (XML) you want to post, then the headers you want to set. It returns the response and the body as a two-element array.

I can't test this because you've obscured the host, and odds are good it takes a registered account, but the code looks correct from what I remember when using Net::HTTP.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse("https://rs.xxx-travel.com/wbsapi/RequestListenerServlet")
https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
https.use_ssl = true
req, body = https.post(uri.path, '<xml><blah></blah></xml>', {"Accept-Encoding" => 'gzip'})
puts "#{body.size} bytes received."
req.each{ |h,v| puts "#{h}: #{v}" }
```

Look at [Typhoeus](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus) as an alternate, and, in my opinion, easier to use gem, especially the "Making Quick Requests" section.

Comment: Thanks Tin Man, your suggestion also worked but I had solved it using the set_debug_output shown below.